# ADS1256 and Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, texas-instruments

My aim is to get my Raspberry Pi 2 connected to an adc ( which will have 8 channels and resolution should be higher than 16 bits or 16 bit )

And according to analog values from load-cells. I am going to make a weighing indicator. with 4 channels.

I have selected Texas Instruments ads1256 chip to do it. 
It is 24 bit delta sigma adc.

First I have made PCB With 2 ads1256.

Simply did not work. Spidev results are random or all result is all FF in hex.
I realised , i need some kernel driver for it. 
I am new to unix/linux raspbian by the way.

I thought , it 's true. It's like trying to communicate through rs232 over a converter that windows driver doesn't exist.

But there is no kernel driver for this. I asked Texas, they answered like we don't have, good day, i am closing this.

Then i found and i bought this product from china !

http://www.waveshare.com/high-precision-ad-da-board.htm

It seemed fine to me. After one week, the card came to me. 
There is an example code after all. I was going to connect this on my raspberry and run the example code and get the adc values.

I did everything on thier instructions.

But turns out it doesn't work. 
http://i57.tinypic.com/2efupgh.jpg

So Please show me the path :D what to do now.

Comment: For the benefit of those of us without mindreading skills: How did you connect the ADS1256 to your raspberry pi? What did your circuit look like? What commands did your send? Exactly what results came back? What did you code look like?

Comment: http://shorttext.com/6720a276

this is the example code i get from the site.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange but this solved as below ;

in manufacturer website , there are instructions list. 2 libraries. bcm2835 and wiringPi  , i have installed bcm first. ( i did not follow top to bottom ) first i installed bcm2835 then wiringPi. Then it worked.

still don't know how.

sudo apt-get install rpi-update
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo raspi-config 
( enable spi and device tree )

install bcm2835
install wiringPi

then it works